# Can TypeScript infer type of a discriminated union via "extracted" boolean logic?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I have been using discriminated unions (DU) more frequently and have come to love them.  I do however have one issue I can't seem to get past.  If you inline a boolean check for the DU, you can rely on TypeScript (TS) to automatically infer the type for you.  However, if you extract the boolean check, TS can no longer narrow to the specific subtype of the DU.  I’m aware of type guards, but I’d like to know why the compiler doesn’t support extracted online checks, specifically.

Is this a known limitation?  Should I file a bug/feature request?

Example here (w/ [TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeVSQFxQEQywbigDMB7YzAOwFcBbAIwgCcoBfPAKDWgCEFlVwImLF3xRaAQwaYAzsAYBLcgHMW7TlAAiAVV5wAPlC7s2AY2LlZUEwAsIJgNYBJYLwAU84Jm0BKBAD5kNigrc0sIAA85cRNgCAATAGFbB14PADp1eCzsXGNg+UIoVwiomPiku3tfJCDgqAB6eqgPKDjiCGkocmIXJQgXckkGYgB3eNrgswtiABsINJniJXdgNJJibwJGqABRBmGpKAAFYcgGUCgAcnXL1vbO7pcI+Utzfkgr7Uu02uY2WoKRXSmWyOCw1QmDSatEoLmA1hezU6hEUEEhU2ks3mi2W6XWm1+bFYQA)):

```js
type A = { type: "A"; foo: number };
type B = { type: "B"; bar: string };
type DU = A | B;

const checkIt = (it: DU) => {
  const extractedCheck = it.type === "A";

  if (extractedCheck) {
    // it does not get narrowed
    console.log(it.foo); // Error: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'DU'.
  }

  if (it.type === "A") {
    // but this is fine
    console.log(it.foo);
  }
};
```

Comment: There's an existing request at [microsoft/TypeScript#12184](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184) so there's no need to file a new one

Comment: Oh, thanks!  I'll definitely go vote for that issue and follow it.

Comment: By the way, you should post that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct since you did answer my original question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### UPDATE FOR TS4.4:

TypeScript 4.4 will introduce support for saving the results of type guards to a `const`, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#44730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730).  At this point, your code example will just work:

```
const checkIt = (it: DU) => {
  const extractedCheck = it.type === "A";

  if (extractedCheck) {
    console.log(it.foo); // okay
  }

};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-dev.20210701#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeVSQFxQEQywbigDMB7YzAOwFcBbAIwgCcoBfPAKDWgCEFlVwImLF3xRaAQwaYAzsAYBLcgHMW7TlAAiAVV5wAPlC7s2AY2LlZUEwAsIJgNYBJYLwAU84Jm0BKBAD5kNigrc0sIAA85cRNgCAATAGFbB14PADp1eCzsXGNg+UIoVwiomPiku3tfJCDgkItiABsINMbiJXdgNJJibwIAen6oYntxEFrmNlqCovTM7Jwsatrgswbm1vbO7tI+ibZWIA)

---

### ANSWER FOR TS4.3 AND BELOW:

There is an existing feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#12184](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184) to allow such type guard results to be "saved" into a named value to be used later.  The request is open but listed as "revisit" because there's no obvious way to implement it in a performant way.  [The word from the lead architect of the language](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184#issuecomment-260162839) is:

> This would require us to track what effects a particular value for one variable implies for *other* variables, which would add a good deal of complexity (and associated performance penalty) to the control flow analyzer. Still, we'll keep it as a suggestion.

So I wouldn't expect to see such a feature in the language anytime soon, unfortunately.

---

My suggestion is just to continue using your inline type check.  If you have a more complex type guard situation it may be worthwhile to make a [user-defined type guard function](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) but I don't see that as an improvement for the case in your example code.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks yeah I meant to state in my question that type-guards aren’t the solution I’m looking for as they do exist but don’t really solve my particular use case elegantly.   I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Currently nope as mentioned by @jcalz, however there's a minimal workaround that you can always apply to overcome this problem.

The trick is to make `extractCheck` a function that returns **type predicate**.
(Refer https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

The following is a working example:

```
type A = { type: "A"; foo: number };
type B = { type: "B"; bar: string };
type DU = A | B;

const checkIt = (it: DU) => {
  // Make `extractCheck` a function 
  const extractedCheck = (it: DU): it is A => it.type === "A";

  if (extractedCheck(it)) {
    console.log(it.foo);  // No error
  }
};
```

Comment: Is this workaround any better than just using the inline check?

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant to mention that I wasn’t looking for typeguards as the answer, as I know they exist.  But you do raise a good point for other to see: if you need a typeguard you can do it like you mentioned!   Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz Maybe a little more DRY?