# Map Interface to { name : keyof Interface, value: Interface[name] }

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure how to describe my problem exactly. Been trying to get this right for some hours and also haven't found a solution online.

Lets take this interface for example:

```
interface MyInterface {
  bool: boolean
  num: number
  str: string
}
```

I tried something like this

```
type MyMappedType<T> = {
  title: keyof T
  value: T[keyof T]
}
```

My problem is that value will be `string | number | booleen`

Therefore this code is valid:

```
const T1: MyMappedType<MyInterface > = { title: "bool", value: 5 }  // this should fail
const T2: MyMappedType<MyInterface > = { title: "bool", value: true }
```

I have the feeling this should be an easy task, but somehow I do not find a solution, but maybe i'm just searching for the wrong thing. Is someone able to help me, or provide a good reference?

Maybe this could work with `infer`, but honestly I never really understood how `infer` works.

Answer (score 1):

You need a discriminated union to achieve this.

```
type MyMappedType = {
    title: 'bool'
    value: boolean
}
| {
    title: 'num'
    value: number
}
| {
    title: 'str'
    value: string
}

const T1: MyMappedType = { title: "bool", value: 5 }  // this fails
const T2: MyMappedType = { title: "bool", value: true }
```

The better understand why your example does not work replace `T` with `MyInterface` (which is what the compiler does):

```
type MyMappedType = {
  title: keyof MyInterface
  value: MyInterface[keyof MyInterface]
}
```

There is no connection between `title` and `value` in there other than that they're props on the same object type. The TS mechanism through which you make the compiler understand that there *should* be a connection is [discriminated unions](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions).

Comment: I understand why it does not work, and I know that I could list them in the discriminated union way. However this is not realistic in my use-case. The example above is extremly simplified. There should be a ways TS can infer which `title`-value I provide, and determine which value should be the correct one.

Comment: I also could use 
`type MyMappedType<T,V extends keyof T> = {  title: keyof T,  value: T[V] }`. But then I would always have to provide the second generic, which is also unrealistic for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61180988/can-typescript-infer-type-of-a-discriminated-union-via-extracted-boolean-logic - there's a good explanation linked to in there for why TS does not support what you need: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184#issuecomment-260162839

Comment: Typeguards are an alternative, but probably even more complex than writing that discriminated union.

Comment: What does work is a constrained identity function. See shorturl.at/hFKT2 (had to short url). However im not sure how to generate an interface with that aproach

Comment: The discussion in the issue I liked to explains that TS does not discriminate a variable's type based on another variable's value. The "CIF" thing does not do that in any way. A "CIF" helps regain existing type constraints after generalising with `Record<string, OperationFn>`. You don't have that "good" initial type to start with, because that one would be the discriminated union...